# Dotted/round vertical line in a div

Tags: jquery, css, html, fluid-layout

I have a div (parent) inside which I've got three main elements:
- dotted line from the top of div to the middle part (to the headline),
- headline,
- dotted line from the middle to the bottom of div

The question is - how to make those dotted lines (working as div with background) fluid, and make their height adaptable to screen height? I've got such fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5wo01f1y/4/

piece of my code:

```
     <section id="whatwedo">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="dots">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="heading"><span>We love</span> <h1>What we do</h1></div>
                    <p>Bakery & Sweets</p>  
                <div class="dots">&nbsp;</div>
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down btn-down"></i>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
 </section>
```

CSS:

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika+Negative:300,400,600,700&subset=latin-ext);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400italic,400,700,700italic&subset=latin-ext);

body {
    font-family:'Signika Negative', sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}

html, body {
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#whatwedo .heading {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#da2027;
    }

#whatwedo .heading span {
    color:#fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:36px;
}

#whatwedo p {
    font-family:'Merriweather', sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:1.7em;
}

#whatwedo{
    background-color:#da2027;
    margin-top:0;
    padding-top: 85px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    text-align:center;
    height:100%;
}

#whatwedo h1 {
    color: white;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:inline-block;
}

.btn-down {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    color:#fff;
}

.dots {
   height:100%;
   margin:0 auto;
    width:9px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url('http://s23.postimg.org/8wexsdl07/dot.png') repeat-x;
}
```

Do I need to use jquery or there might be a simplier hack?

Comment: Dotted lines are intended to be vertical? Because in the css the repeat of the background of the .dots is set as `... repeat-x;`.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Muthukumaru/5k7qLmjs/1/
use this css for top dot

```
.heading span:before{
content: "\00a0 ";
background: transparent url("http://s23.postimg.org/8wexsdl07/dot.png") repeat-x scroll 0% 0%;
width:9px;
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left:49%
}
```

for bottom dot use a class for p tag like `<p class="dot1">Bakery & Sweets</p>`

```
.dot1:before{
content: "\00a0 ";
background: transparent url("http://s23.postimg.org/8wexsdl07/dot.png") repeat-x scroll 0% 0%;
width:9px;
position: absolute;
bottom:0px;
left:49%
}
```

I aligned  middle of the dot i used left:49%. if u think this value is not matched. set a exact middle use the "calc" like `left:calc(50% - 9px);` we are reducing the 9px width

Comment: hey, thanks. but your code seems not to work (refering to jsfiddle) - dot is repeated only once.

Comment: if you want repeated dots then increase the width  of both class and change the left position 
http://jsfiddle.net/Muthukumaru/5k7qLmjs/2/